# Ошибка при загрузке

Tags: json, unity3d

## Описание

Есть у меня функция сохранения -

```cs
public List<Structs.User> Users = new List<Structs.User>();

public void AddButtonClick()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("UsersList", JsonUtility.ToJson(Users));//Основной часть
    Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("UsersList"));//Нужен для дальнейшего объяснения
    Debug.Log(Users.Count);//Нужен для дальнейшего объяснения
}
```

И функция загрузки -

```cs
public void RefreshList()
{
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("UsersList"))
    {
        Users = new List<Structs.User>();
    }
    else
    {
        Users = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Structs.User>>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("UsersList"));//Основной часть
        Debug.Log(Users.Count);//Нужен для дальнейшего объяснения
    }
}
```

Те `Debug.Log`-и которые были в коде, были неспроста. С помощью них я хотел доказать, что у меня сохранение проходит нормально (как минимум - ключ для сохранения создаётся), но во время загрузки что-то не так загружается.

В [картинке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wqjf.png) видно, что во время загрузки не загружается список.

[image]

---

## Вопрос

Где моя ошибка?
Как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите код класса/структуры `Structs.User`.

Comment: Вы добавляли атрибут Serialize к структуре и её полям ?

Comment: И скорее всего у вас не выйдет считать лист. Попробуйте в фориче передавать каждое значение листа и его уже сохранять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что Unity не умеет сериализовать "лист". Это связано с тем, как создаются списки в json. Поэтому ему нужно сериализовать объект, который включает в себя лист. Другими словами, если вы добавите класс, в котором будет лист и будете сохранять уже этот класс - то всё будет работать нормально. (не забудьте добавить классу атрибут `[System.Serialize]` )

Comment: Извините за опоздание, у меня не было свободного времени. Я в течении 3 дней проверю всё что вы сказали и если оно поможет обязательно поставлю галочку.